# Store ogg packets into ogg file node js

Tags: node.js, ogg

I'm trying to write a simple audio stream in node. I have a streamer (A client) which sends ogg packets (over network), But I have no idea how to write these packets into a ogg file which can be played with a audio player. I've read [Node-Ogg](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-ogg) code and examples but it's node provide the interface, I needed. I write packets into file but it's not playable.

Any help?